# Accessing function and model in one controller from another view's controller UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have 2 view A and B with their respective controllers and models defined inside. Due to some reason I have to move 2 elements from A to B view. One of the element is a button link with a press event. I moved the elements to another view but when I click on the link, it does not trigger press. Which I understand is because B 's controller does not have function for that. If I write the same function in B's controller I get an error saying the model's setProperty could not be set as not found. Because that model is in scope in A's controller only. How do I access it?

Press event of link:

```
pressEvent: function(oEvent) {
        this.getModel("stock").setProperty("/Links/Visible", true);
        var stockroomsarr = this.getModel("stockRms").getProperty("/Stockrooms");

        if (stockrooms !== null && stockrooms.length > 0) {
            this.getModel("stock").setProperty("/Text/Visible", false);
        }
        this.getModel("stock").refresh(false);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Model: I strongly advice not to have own models for each controllers. Instead you should define and set them in the init of your component.js. They then are accessable in the view controller by calling

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("urModel")
```

Another variant would be to create a baseController. In that you can define functions which are to be used by multiple controllers as well as your models. All other controllers extend that baseController, so the models are available in all of them via:

```
this.getView().getModel("urModel")
```

Regarding the function you may use the Event Bus. In short it allows you to create events that are triggered in controller A and are listned to in controller B. Read up here for detailed information on how to use it:
https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/25/openui5-sapui5-communication-between-controllers-using-publish-and-subscribe-from-eventbus/

Comment: moreover, I would strongly advise to use metadata.json approach for declaring models (from the technical point of view). From the modelling point of view, I would separate models to different models only if they are *logically* separate, which dosesnt seem to be the case in this example.